# How to reference a website usercontrol in the c# windows application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, web

i have a solution in windows C# application in which i also have a website. In the website i have 1 usercontrol. now i want the usercontrol to be used in the other c# project of the same solution. how to do it?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?

Answer (score 2):

That cannot be done. You have to recreate it for the windows application. What you can reuse are business logics (if they are in a different class library) and web services.